# Python loop for multi statement

Tags: python, declare

Simple declare in python is like.

```
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1
```

make it easier...

```
x,y,z = [1] * 3
```

but for function "statement"...

```
    import wx
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.exc11, id=exc11id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.exc15, id=exc15id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.exc37, id=exc37id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.exc55, id=exc55id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.exc88, id=exc88id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.exc99, id=exc99id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.rexc11, id=rexc11id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.rexc15, id=rexc15id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.rexc37, id=rexc37id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.rexc55, id=rexc55id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.rexc88, id=rexc88id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.rexc99, id=rexc99id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.excel11, id=excel11id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.excel15, id=excel15id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.excel37, id=excel37id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.excel55, id=excel55id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.excel88, id=excel88id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.excel99, id=excel99id)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.calc, id=calcid)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.edit, id=editid)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.next, id=nextid)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.prev, id=previd)
```

Why can I just use loop for multi-declare?
e.g

```
for x in "exc11 exc15 exc37 exc55 exc88 exc99".split():
    xid = x + "id"
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.x, id=x)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ns = vars()
for x in "exc11 exc15 exc37 exc55 exc88 exc99".split():
    xid = x + "id"
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, getattr(self, x), id=ns[xid])
```

---

Whenever variable names contain numbers it is usually a sign that you should be using a list, tuple or dict instead of multiple variable. Use a list or tuple if the order of the variables is important, otherwise a dict may be more appropriate. Use a list if it the number of values is mutable, use a tuple otherwise.

For example, instead of variables

`exc11id exc15id exc37id exc55id exc88id exc99id`

you could use a dict:

```
excid = {'11': ..., '15': ..., }
```

and similarly instead of having lots of attributes, you could have a single attribute `self.exc` which is a dict:

```
self.exc = {'11': ..., '15': ..., }
```

If you make this change, then the code could be simplified to

```
for x in "11 15 37 55 88 99".split():
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.exc[x], id=excid[x])
```

---

The reason why

```
for x in "exc11 exc15 exc37 exc55 exc88 exc99".split():
    xid = x + "id"
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.x, id=x)
```

does not work is because the values referenced by `x` and `xid` are `str`s. When you write `self.x` Python is looking for an attribute whose name is `x`, not an attribute whose name is the value referenced by the variable `x`. 
Instead, [`getattr(self, x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) is the function call you are looking for.

Similarly, `xid` is just a string. To get the value referenced by the variable whose name is the same as the value of that string, you need to look up the value in the [vars()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) or [globals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) namespace.

Comment: Thx a lot
First post on stackoverflow
Just surprising how fast I can get a answer

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
menus = [
    (self.exc11, exc11id),
    (self.exc15, exc15id),
    (self.exc37, exc37id),
    (self.exc55, exc55id),
    (self.exc88, exc88id),
    (self.exc99, exc99id),
    (self.rexc11, rexc11id),
    (self.rexc15, rexc15id),
    (self.rexc37, rexc37id),
    (self.rexc55, rexc55id),
    (self.rexc88, rexc88id),
    (self.rexc99, rexc99id),
    (self.excel11, excel11id),
    (self.excel15, excel15id),
    (self.excel37, excel37id),
    (self.excel55, excel55id),
    (self.excel88, excel88id),
    (self.excel99, excel99id),
    (self.calc, calcid),
    (self.edit, editid),
    (self.next, nextid),
    (self.prev, previd),
]

for handler, id_ in menus:
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, handler, id=id_)
```

Comment: Sorry.
But I wanna make all statement in loop
My method is wasting "lines"